# How to create a user in Heroku console

Tags: heroku

I want to create a user in Heroku and want to give specific permission to this user to certain folder.

I've logged into heroku bash but I'm not able to create a user. It's giving me permission denied error. sudo also not working. I can't install anything in it.
Organisation admin user also not able to create a user.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku will not allow you to do that.
Running `heroku run bash` is not the same as connecting to an SSH server.

When you build a new version of your application, Heroku will create a new container (much like Docker. It's LXC). Any instance of your application will run that container.
When you run a bash instance, a new instance of that container is created. You are not running on the same server as your app serves requests on.

That means the only moment when disk changes can be performed is at build time. So even if you could create users in a bash instance, those wouldn't be persisted accross instances.
Heroku will not let you create new linux users at build time anyway.

The only solution to access your app's code in a bash session is to run a one-off dyno. If you need to script that, you can use the [platform api](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#dyno-create) to boot a new dyno.

As for adding access, you can use the [access:add](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/collaborating) command (also available as an [api endpoint](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#collaborator-create)).
All users will be able to access all of your code though. You cannot restrict per folder.